# Derive Bernoulli-equation from first law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, bernoulli-equation

I am currently working on my bachelor's thesis and I am trying to derive Bernoulli's equation which can be used for changing temperatures. Let's say I got a pipe with inflow-area $A_1$ and outflow-area $A_2$. I also know the heat I am feeding into the pipe $\dot{Q}$. Furthermore, the inflow velocity and inflow pressure are known. I also know the pressure loss from friction $\Delta p_r$

I am going to assume that the density of my fluid will not change a lot. This means that I can get the outflow velocity using:

$$v_2 = v_1 \cdot \dfrac{A_2}{A_1}$$

Applying the first law of thermodynamics:

$$
0 = \dot{Q}+\sum_i \dot{m}_i \left( h_i+g\cdot z_i+\frac{c_i^2}{2}\right)
$$

Since I want to get an equation similar to Bernoulli's equation with an additional temperature term, I would first split $h_i$ into something depending on the pressure and the temperature.

$$h_i = c_p\cdot T+p\cdot?$$
I am very unsure of how this should be formulated and even derived. I would end up plugging this one back into the first law of thermodynamics and ideally end up with the Bernoulli equation with a temperature term.

I am very happy for any help or advice!

Comment: So some here may argue that a constant density will be wrong due to a change in temperature. In theory I could also iteratively solve this problem by assuming a varying density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bernoulli does *not apply* when heat is being added, or when there is friction.

It does apply compressible fluids whose temperature is changing due to compression.

Bernoulli's theorem uses the specific enthalpy $h$   (i.e $U+PV$ per unit mass). It is a generalization of the statement that the enthalpy is conserved in throttling processes to include the kinetic energy of the fluid.

Bernoulli says that in steady barotropic flow --- ie  when density only dependes on the pressure ---the quantity
$$
\frac 12 |V|^2 + h+gz
$$
is constant along streamlines. You can easily derive it from Euler's equation
$$
\rho\left(\frac {\partial {\bf v}}{\partial t} + ({\bf v}\cdot \nabla) {\bf v}\right)= -\nabla P.
$$

The key property of the enthalpy is when $dS=0$ we have
$$
h(P) = \int_0^P \frac{dP}{\rho(P)},
$$
so that $\rho \nabla h= \nabla P$.

Comment: I do know that Bernoulli does not simply apply in the form I know. A friction term can be added as a pressure loss term. Assuming I know the pressure loss due to friction, should I perhaps put that back into the first law of thermodynamics and work with that?

So my main issue is that my temperature changes due to compression AND a heat source.

Comment: I suggest you use the constant entropy version first, so that you understand all the thermodynamic aspects of that case, and only then figure out what can be rescued when you include entropy changing effects such as viscocity.  In a throttling process there is friction but no heat is being added or removed from the fluid.

Comment: So this should ideally not be too complex since my thesis focuses on other parts. What assumptions would you make in my case? I might even get away with saying that there is no friction yet ideally I need to know the pressure loss inside my pipe

Comment: A Batchelor's thesis is not usually required to contain original research (althogh it helps!) so I'd search the literature and see what there is ou there already.

Comment: So I assume I should probably assume no loss of entropy. Which means I can get away with just ignoring pressure at all? Using your first equation. I am not sure how one would bring back the heat source into your equations.

Comment: I just realised that the entropy of my fluid will change once i add heat. This makes things more complicated

Answer (score 2):

Bernoulli's equation focuses only on mechanical energy while the first law focuses on every kind of energy (including mechanical).  Also, unless you specially include the effects of viscous drag in Bernoulli'e equation, it will not properly nclude all the different kinds of mechanical energy. Once the mechanical energy balance equation is properly expressed, it can be subtracted from the first law equation (overall energy balance) to yield a new equation which might be called the "thermal energy balance equation" (which includes temperature changes and viscous heating).  See Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena, for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The Bernoulli equation can include a term for friction loss, and this is appropriate if there is little change in the fluid state. For significant changes in the fluid state, the first law is needed.  As @ Chet Miller suggests, see the Bird, Stewart, Lightfoot text for a detailed explanation.

Comment: But if I use the first law, I have no information about the pressure or am I mistaken?

Comment: The first law considers the internal energy in the system and the flow of mass (enthalpy) in and out of the system. Both internal energy and enthalpy depend on the state of the fluid which in general depends on the pressure.  (For an ideal gas, a special case, internal energy and enthalpy both depend only on temperature.)  Your original question illustrates that many texts do not address this issue very well if at all.   The Bird, Stewart, Lightfoot text does explain it.

Comment: I do assume that I work with ideal gases. Yet I am unable to figure out which formulas to apply beside continuity equation and the first law of TD. How do I figure out the temperature and the pressure of the fluid at the same time?

Comment: The Bernoulli equation provides no information on temperature since it assumes friction loss only changes the mechanical energy (eg pressure in a flowing pipe).  The mass balance, momentum equation, and first law (energy balance) provide the set of relationships needed but in general are complicated to solve.  See the Bird, ... textbook.